# how to show window title using window.open()?

Tags: javascript, title, window.open

I want to open a new window using:

```
window.open('<myfile>.pdf','my window','resizable,scrollbars');
```

The new window opens, but I do not get the title of the window as 'my window'.
What could be going wrong?

Comment: The second argument to `window.open()` is the new window's *name*, not its title. The actual title comes from the `<title>` element of the HTML document loaded into that window. Since you're loading a PDF file, it will be left to the discretion of your browser.

Comment: Is there no workaround for this? I really need to get the title for the new window that is opening the pdf.

Comment: I don't know of any workaround, short of writing an add-on for every browser you want to support.

Comment: And the window name can not have spaces or IE will not open up the pop up. :)

Answer (score 46):

If domain is same then you can change the title of new window

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var w = window.open('http://localhost:4885/UMS2/Default.aspx');
    w.document.title = 'testing';
 </script>
```

Comment: Try adding a `setTimeout` like this:
`setTimeout(() => w.document.title = 'This is a test',0);`

Comment: setTimeout() helps, just add 50ms instead of 0ms.

Answer (score 19):

Here is my solution, please check this out:

```
var myWindow = window.open('<myfile>.pdf','my window','resizable,scrollbars');
myWindow.document.write('<title>My PDF File Title</title>');
```

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenWindow() {
            var pdf = '<%= "PDFs/13.7/" + ddlLinkValidation.SelectedValue.ToString() + ".pdf" %>';
            var win = window.open('','UATRpt', 'menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1,status=1,scrollbars=1');

            if(win.document) { 
                win.document.write('<html><head><title>Your Report Title</title></head><body height="100%" width="100%"><iframe src="' + pdf + '" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe></body></html>');
            } 
            return true;
    } 
    </script>
```

in HTML body 
 
`<U><A style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="OpenWindow()">Open in New Window</a></U>`

Comment: its working for setting title of page but it also set blank url of page so download  link not working. any suggestion for it ?

Answer (score 5):

The JavaScript "title" argument is a variable to be used inside of JavaScript. The actual title written in the top of the window normally comes from the HTML `<title>` tag, but you don't have that since you're showing a PDF.

Comment: Is there no way in which I can get the title for the new window?

Answer (score 4):

If the new window has a file (PDF for example) as an url, it’s possible that **the page has no "head" tag**.

You have to add one before to modify / add the title.

**jQuery :**

```
var w = window.open('/path/to/your/file.pdf');// or any url
$(w.document).find('html').append('<head><title>your title</title></head>');
```

**Native js :**

```
var w = window.open('/path/to/your/file.pdf');// or any url
w.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
   .appendChild(document.createElement('head'))
   .appendChild(document.createElement('title'))
   .appendChild(document.createTextNode('your title'));
```

Now if the page is long to load, you may add a onload watch, then also a timeout. In my case, I had to code like that :

```
var w = window.open('/path/to/your/file.pdf');// or any url
w.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(w.document).find('html').append('<head><title>your title</title></head>');
    }, 500);
} // quite ugly hu !? but it works for me.
```

Comment: As to jQuery, while preserving the $(…) object, instead of specifying the .find method, I should rather go for $(w.document.lastChild) —it must be faster.

Answer (score 4):

**To change title of pdf in newly opened window**

```
    function titlepath(path,name){

        //In this path defined as your pdf url and name (your pdf name)

            var prntWin = window.open();
            prntWin.document.write("<html><head><title>"+name+"</title></head><body>"
                + '<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="'+ path+ '" '
                + 'type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="21"></body></html>');
            prntWin.document.close();
        }
```

**Onclick**

```
<a onclick="titlepath('your url','what title you want')">pdf</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code works to me on Mozilla Firefox, IE 11 and Google Chrome.

```
var winUrl = 'target URL that needs to open in new window';     

var _newWindow = window.open(winUrl, "_newWindow");

_newWindow.document.title = "My New Title";
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way to accomplish the task.  Sometimes obvious is obvious and complicated is a major waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way it worked in my case was using [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) like this:

```
var mapWin = window.open('', '_blank', ''); // Opens a popup   

setWindowTitle(mapWin) // Starts checking

function setWindowTitle(mapWin)
{
    if(mapWin.document) // If loaded
    {
        mapWin.document.title = "Oil Field Map";
    }
    else // If not loaded yet
    {
        setTimeout(setWindowTitle, 10); // Recheck again every 10 ms
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const wnd = window.open(url, '_blank');

wnd.onload = function() {
   wnd.document.title = 'YOUR TITLE';
}
```

Comment: I love this listenable way

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400');
    setTimeout(function(){ myWindow.document.title = 'my new title'; }, 1000);
```

works chrome 2018

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing the html doc: setting the pdf url to an iframe and letting the title tag define the page title.

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.write(`<html>
  <head>
    <title>${title}</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <iframe src="${pdfInlineUrl}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myWindow = window.open('<myfile>.pdf', 'my-window');
if (myWindow ) {
    const title = myWindow.document.createElement('title');
    title.innerText = 'my window title';
    myWindow.document.head.append(title);
}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76180159/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this

```js
 function printData(id) {
            console.log(id); //belongs to Div ID
            var divToPrint = document.getElementById(id);
            var newWin = window.open('');
            newWin.document.write('<title>Invoice</title>');
            newWin.document.title = id;
            newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML );
            
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button onclick="printData('question-header')" class="btn btn-light text-capitalize border-0" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fas fa-print text-primary"></i> Print</button>
```