# Window Title for ASHX Handler

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, httphandler, window.open

I am building an ASP.NET site and one of its features is that when a link is clicked, it opens a new tab.  The link is called an ASHX Http Handler that does some process behind the scenes.  What I want is to be able to take the text of the link (say for example if a person clicked on a link that says Document 100.txt) and have it displayed in the window title of the newly opened ASHX Http Handler.

I am currently using: 
`Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", "<script>window.open('Handler.ashx?fileName=" + fileName + "');</script>", false);`

This opens the handler perfectly, only I cannot get the title to display for the new tab.  This would be beneficial because a user can open any number of links at once, and at a glance he or she should be able to differentiate what tab is what based on the window title.

I have tried something like 
`var w = window.open(...); w.document.title=fileName`
and
`var w = window.open(...); w.document.write('<title>' + fileName + '</title>');`

and none of these work properly (since I am writing to the context object in the handler, it would be difficult to write to it to add a title as well).

If anyone has some ideas or suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What are you writing to context object?

Comment: depends on file type - if it is a pdf file the user wishes to view, then use iTextSharp to get byte array and write that - if image then simply convert to byte array and write to context - if text do the same only handle for text rather than image...either way it ends up being a byte array using "content-length" and NOT "content-disposition" when adding context header to output stream

Comment: What I'm actually doing to view a pdf, is converting the filepath of the pdf to a byte array and loading that into the context.Response header as "content-length" (I'm using iTextSharp to print the file from a web browser automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is quite old now so unfortunately you may have moved on but to those who find this in the future. I was trying to do something similar. ASP site had links to a folder with PDF reports. ASHX handler ran to ensure authorization, then it transmitted the appropriate pdf, opening it up in a new tab/window using `window.open(...)`. For reference, these were the browsers I was testing in:

- Chrome V60.0.3112.113
- Firefox V55.0.3
- Edge V40.15063.0.0
- IE11

Using anything of the like:

```
var newWin = window.open("PrivateFileHandler.ashx?VariablesForTheHandler");

// add a load listener to the window so that the title gets changed on the page load
newWin.addEventListener("load", function() {
    newWin.document.title = "NewTitle";
});
```

did not work. I had pulled that idea from a SO [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27847006/3942263).

Once I realized that there was no `<head>` to even add a `<title>` to I tried this:

```
newWin.addEventListener("load", function() {
    newWin.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
    .appendChild(newWin.document.createElement('head'))
    .appendChild(newWin.document.createElement('title'))
    .appendChild(newWin.document.createTextNode('NewTitle'));
});
```

Which I had derived from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299858/3942263) on SO. Chrome ignored the 'NewTitle' in the `<title>` field when it was added this way. Although when I manually changed it using the Developer F12 tools the tab's title changed. I couldn't get it to work automatically. Firefox and Edge overwrote the entire `<head>`. And by that point I didn't even try it in IE11. All of my new tabs still had "PrivateFileHandler.ashx..."

There are a few permutations of my JS code samples in the questions/answers of the two links above. Ie. using `newWin.onload = function(){ ... };` instead of the `addEventListener( ... )` function. There's a JQuery option to add the `<head>`, and another solution that takes advantage of the `setTimeout(...)` function. Feel free to refer to those links and answers to try those solutions out. However, given my testing, those options weren't going to make a difference for me.

My initial goal like @J-man above was to put the name of the pdf file that was being transmitted into the tab title. My solution actually didn't involve any changes to my javascript. To do this I removed the web config I had in my reports folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <denyUrlSequences>
            <add sequence="/" />
          </denyUrlSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This had initially closed down my folder so that only the PrivateFileHandler (and not IIS) could transmit the PDF. Then following [this MSDN guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx), I configured my application to send all requests for reports/xxx.pdf through my PrivateFileHandler.

```
<handlers>
  <add name="PrivateFileHandler" verb="*"
    path="Reports/*.pdf"
    type="PrivateFileHandler"
    resourceType="File" />
</handlers>
```

I was running IIS 7.0 in Integrated mode. There are instructions there on doing the same in IIS 6.0 as well as IIS 7.0 in Classic mode. My PrivateFileHandler needed a little bit of tweaking to handle this sort of request, but then when it delivered the PDF content the browser tab titles were the name of the PDF.

SIDENOTE - if you are wanting to open files in new tabs/windows, important to include this header in your `Response`:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + FileName + "\"")
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll have to try it out when I can, but from what I can see I like it.  Thanks!