# How to set the title for the new browser tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question about the new tab for the link.

Is there anyway I can set the browser tab title before user clicks a link? It seems like there is no way to debate the title for the new tab if the html contained in the new tab doesn't have title attribute. Am I right? How do I set the title?

```
//the href is dynamic so I can't set them one by one because I have 100+ html file here
<a href="test.html" target="_blank">open me<a>
```

Comment: You mean `document.title = 'foo';`?

Comment: `href` is dynamic so you must have some info on those pages coming from your DB or whatever. So set them there when a page loads ...

Comment: how own the new tab page? you or is an external link? cause if its you could set the title over the url as parameter and consume it when the tab its open

Comment: You mean that you want to pass the title for the next page with your link?

Comment: @PaulS. I can't do that because it opens a new tab and I could have more than 100+ html file to open. I don't have the access  to those html files and they don't specify title in the html

Comment: @nicael yes. That's what I am asking. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have access, are those third-party pages in a different domain? If so, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @BonJon Is the page you are going to yours?

Comment: No, it isn't possible unless your pages have some javascript in it that can handle get params to set the title. like: <a href="page.html?title=My new title" target="_blank">click me</a>

Comment: @nicael yes it will be mine(same domain)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have it, this is not possible because your links are just normal HTML links. When the new page opens in a new tab, the current page will not have any reference to it and so cannot change it in any way. You will need to open the page using javascript and set the title that way.

You can dynamically set this up in `window onload` to find all `a` tags and add a `click` event whihc opens the window and sets the title.

If you want different titles for each page, you can store this in a `data-` attribute in the `a` tag.

Note tho that this will only work with pages in the same domain (for security), and that it does not handle people right clicking and pressing "Open in New Window". Middle click in Windows does seem to work however.

**HTML**

```
<a href="test.html" data-title="A new page" target="_blank">open me</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    // does the actual opening
    function openWindow(event) {
        event = event || window.event;

        // find the url and title to set
        var href = this.getAttribute("href");
        var newTitle = this.getAttribute("data-title");
        // or if you work the title out some other way...
        // var newTitle = "Some constant string";

        // open the window
        var newWin = window.open(href, "_blank");

        // add a load listener to the window so that the title gets changed on page load
        newWin.addEventListener("load", function() {
            newWin.document.title = newTitle;
        });

        // stop the default `a` link or you will get 2 new windows!
        event.returnValue =  false;
    }

    // find all a tags opening in a new window
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[target=_blank][data-title]");
    // or this if you don't want to store custom titles with each link
    //var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[target=_blank]");

    // add a click event for each so we can do our own thing
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener("click", openWindow.bind(links[i]));
    }

});
```

[**Sample JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/42p55c6o/6/)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the title with hash and get it on another page, if this another page is yours and you can modify its code.

1st page:

```
...
<a href="test.html#the_title_you_want" target="_blank">open me<a>
...
```

2nd page - modify the body opening tag like this:

```
<body onload="document.title=window.location.hash.replace('#','');">
```

If the page you are linking to isn't yours, you can use `window.open` method:

```
<a href="javascript:var mw = window.open('test.html');mw.document.title = 'the_title_you_want';">open me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Nicael, I think I misunderstood your question. They are in the same domain but I don't have access to the 2nd page. +1 though

Comment: I tried the last option  - not working for me either

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen addEventListener work reliably, especially when opening a new page using javascript. The best way to change the tab title and have it work reliably is to set a timeout until the page loads. You may have to play with the timeout value, but it works.

```
var newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');

setTimeout(function () {
    newWindow.document.title = "My Tab Name";
}, 100);
```

Comment: Nice idea but it gets a cross-origin permission error on some systems

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Using pure HTML, you can let the user open up links, then later on change the title. Or you can change the title with inline JavaScript. Here's how you do both:

### Method 1

Change your links by assigning a target attribute, and then later on use that window name to control the document. For instance in your links it would be: `<a href="whatever" target="theNewWindow">`. Whenever you want to change the title for this page, you'd use JavaScript as such: `window.open("", "theNewWindow").document.title = "New Page Title!";` The problem with this method however is that all links with that target/window name will open in that same window. In addition, after the first time the link is clicked, your browser won't automatically switch to the new tab/window.

### Method 2

Change your links by assigning an onclick attribute, which would open the link manually and change the title of the page immediately. Basically it would come down to look like: `<a href="whatever" onclick="var w=window.open(this.href, '_blank'); (w.onload=function(){w.document.title='New Page Title!';})(); return false;">`. This opens the window based on the href attribute, immediately changes the title, and sets the window to change the title to that when it finishes loading (just in case there really was a title tag).

---

The problem with both of these methods (as mentioned by others) is your html files have to be on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is a follows:

```
var winTab = window.open("", "_blank")

//Open URL by writing iframe with given URL

winTab.document.write("write iframe with your url in src here")

//Set Title for the new tab

winTab.document.title = "Form Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own Page 2 that opens up the other pages (the ones you can't edit), in a frameset.  You can then either change the title dynamically when loading your page 2, or as others have suggested if you use window.open you can control the title from the parent page.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in page 1, and opening page 2 in a new tab, you can't set title for page 2 from page 1.

If you have access to page 2 then it's possible, otherwise not.

Comment: Actually you can set the title when opening a tab with JS instead of a link. In this case the domain must be the same ofcourse.

Comment: @Teemu how? suppose they are on same domain. how can you change title of page 2 without touching page 2?

Comment: Open the tab using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open), that way you'll get a reference to the tab's `window` and everything inside it.