# How to set the popup window title?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to open a new popup window by giving the title and the url. I have something like this.

Html

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openLink(link)">Open me<a>
```

my controller file.

```
$scope.openLink = function(link) {
    $window.open(link.url).document.title = link.title
}
 //I am sure link.title is not undefined.
```

The above code will open the new tab with the url. However, I want to control the popup window's title. Is that possible?

The url and my site are in the same domain. My codes above won't set the title even if the targeted url doesn't have title attribute setup. I had a similar post but it is not angular solution. 
[How to set the title for the new browser tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846474/how-to-set-the-title-for-the-new-browser-tab)
Is there a way to fix it in angular way. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since *$window* just references the window, it is basically `window.open(link.url)` for which you can use

```
var win = window.open('', 'foo', ''); // open popup

function check() {
    if(win.document) { // if loaded
        win.document.title = "test"; // set title
    } else { // if not loaded yet
        setTimeout(check, 10); // check in another 10ms
    }
}

check(); // start checking
```

to set the title when page has been loaded. The code is straight from [Stewie Griffins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501424/set-title-in-the-window-popup).

Comment: It's working well for blank page, but to open pdf file in new tab this is not working

Comment: @Venkat currently i am looking for the solution. I need to set title for pdf file which opened on new tab.