# Browser tab title with Angular when using window.open(...)

Tags: angular, typescript, web

In the code behind, I open a new browser tab (window) with a PDF as content, from data as blob from the server.
It works, a new tab opens with the document, but the title of the tab of the browser is some hex code.
Could dynamically I change this browser tab title? "Document" for example?

Here is the code I use (sorry, could not do a StackBlitz sample as the data comes from a server):

> const file = new Blob([data], {type:'application/pdf'});
>
> const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
>
> window.open(fileURL, '_blank');

And here, how my browser tab looks like:

[image: Browser tab]

Solution (works in Chrome and Edge):

```
var w = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
setTimeout(function(){ w.document.title = 'My title'; }, 500);
```

Other solution (works in Chrome, FF and Edge):

```
var w = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
w.document.write('<html><head><title>My title</title></head><body height="100%" width="100%"><iframe src="' + fileURL+ '" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe></body></html>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this post [how to show window title using window.open()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051811/how-to-show-window-title-using-window-open) ?

There're several ways of achieving this suggested by community

Comment: Thanks, I've found a solution there.