# Customize header title of iframe when serving base64 encoded PDF

Tags: html

this happens on Chrome

what is the workaround to change it? see image below

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,${data}" type="application/pdf" />
```

the header title is showing the `${data}` value (I believe)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways this issue can manifest but as a general issue it is the lack of a tab title needs some other tag, and blob in transit has no metadata other than its content so that is used finally its title.

If you decode that string you will see it includes "endstream" a sure sign it is the PDF raw data as text.

The relative order is blob will start with either its ID= or its DataURL=JVBER... style content then the PDF/frame/HTML/window Title may be used to be shown on the tab or frame border.

For workarounds via replace HTML Title (usually timeout delay set for after the Base64 has landed) see

[how to show window title using window.open()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051811/how-to-show-window-title-using-window-open)

However I recommend dont try to pop-up an about:blank replacement as tab jacking will often be blocked or fail. Try to ensure you use an inline frame in a html carrier page.

If the iFrame is in a HTML carrier, as it looks like it is here, then simply ensure the `<head>`er area includes

```
<head>
...
<title>MyPDF compliments of Your name goes here</title>
...
</head>
```

and the

```
<iframe title="My book for you" src="data...etc download="filename as required.pdf" >Description for users</iframe>
```

Also if possible ensure the PDF has an inbedded /Title=

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [embed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed)-tag for this:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="data:application/pdf;base64,${data}" type="application/pdf" />
```

Comment: I think this could be a solution if you mention that the `embed` tag has the possibility to have a `title`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed - but, also the iframe has a title