Set pdf name using EMBED and URL.createObjectURL (not for download)
I'm using embed to render a PDF file inside an HTML document. If I proceed as follows:
const embed = document.createElement("EMBED");

const url = "../pdf_files/test.pdf";
embed.src = url;

const content = document.getElementById("content");
content.innerHTML = "";
content.appendChild(embed);

the browser pdf viewer renders the document using the filename, as highlighted in the image below:

But if I use Blob/File/URL.createObjectURL, the pdf viewer does not use the file name:
const embed = document.createElement("EMBED");
const url = "../pdf_files/test.pdf";

const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());

const blob = new Blob([existingPdfBytes], {
    type: 'application/pdf'
});
const file = new File([blob], "hello.pdf", {"type": "application/pdf"});

embed.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)

const content = document.getElementById("content");
content.innerHTML = "";
content.appendChild(embed);


Is there a way to set this file name in order to display it properly on the pdf viewer using URL.createObjectURL?
Comment regarding potential duplicates
This question is not about downloading a file.

In both cases it is using the filename. The objectURL is the name. The file internally probably does not have a Title or the file internally does not have the flag set to use the document title

As Kevin Brown pointed out already, essentially the same thing is happening in both scenarios: The last part of the url is displayed at the top.
embed.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
console.log(embed.src) // This will show you the url which ends with a uid

Maybe you want to try and set the title of the <embed> to the file name manually:
embed.setAttribute("title", url.split("/").pop())


Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work.

There is only one common way to tag an objects carrier and that is to specify the Tab Title.
So you are using HTML  and if you also add HTML <title> My name </title> in the files  it should title the tab. For icon consider a linked favicon too.
A fuller description was given as a previous answer.

If the embed is in a HTML carrier, as it looks like it is here, then simply ensure the <head>er area includes

<head>
...
<title>MyPDF compliments of Your name goes here</title>
...
</head>

and the body either your embedment or
<iframe title="My book for you" src="data...etc download="filename as required.pdf" >Description for users</iframe>

Also if possible ensure the PDF has an enbedded /Title=
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75886544/10802527
